# Let one control be enabled/disabled based on another control

Tags: wpf, dependencies

I have two DataGrid's that I want do have enabled/disabled based on whether precisely 1 element is selected in another DataGrid. What is the simplest way to accomplish this dependency control in WPF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a trigger:

```
    <DataGrid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItems.Count,
                                               ElementName=datagrid1}"
                            Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could:

- Create an `IValueConverter`, perhaps it is called `NotEqualToOneBooleanConverter`
- Bind `IsEnabled` from one `DataGrid` to the `SelectedItems.Count` on the other
- Set the `Converter` on this `Binding` to be the `NotEqualToOneBooleanConverter`

This approach is nice since once your converter is created, it can be applied throughout your XAML and to any type and any property (not just `DataGrid` or `SelectedItems.Count`). To make it even more flexible, you could have a more generic version of this converter that could compare any two values specified directly from XAML (one from the `Binding` and one specified as property on the `Converter`).

The downside to this approach - it's XAML only, and difficult to test especially if what you are trying to achieve is a business requirement and not just a graphical effect.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is my quick hack:

```
    tablesControl.SelectionChanged += (sender, sce) =>
    {
        var c = tablesControl.SelectedItems.Count;
        var orderingPossible = c == 1;
        itemsControl.IsEnabled = orderingPossible;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first Grid have an event or Command that is fired when you click on that cell, in this event you need to have some bool property you can set to false, then bind the Enabled property to this bool. If you are using MVVM this will be very easy, have a look at this to see how - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKfpvs7ZIyo